# Elastic Search match phrase query -> output not predictable

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, phrase

### Sample doc

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "title": "Quick Brown fox jumps over the lazy dog",
  "genre": [
    "fiction"
  ]
}
```

### Mapping

```
{
  "movies" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "genre" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### **Query1:** Results in the document shared earlier

```
{
 "query": {
   "match_phrase": {
     "title": {
       "query": "fox quick over", "slop": 3
     }
   }
 } 
}
```

### **Query2:** No Results

```
{
 "query": {
   "match_phrase": {
     "title": {
       "query": "over fox quick", "slop": 3
     }
   }
 } 
}
```

I was expecting a result in query2 rather than in query 1.

Comment: Please share your index mappings as well. It will be easier to debug the query.

Comment: @Harshit: Hey...  added mapping . thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Slop**

> Number of times you need to move a term in order to make the query and document match.
>
> Switching word order requires two edits/steps

Below is movement of words

**Query 1:**

```
            Pos 1         Pos 2         Pos 3     Pos 4     Pos 5   Pos 6  Pos 7   Pos 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Doc:        quick         brown         fox       jumps     over    the   lazy    dog
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Query:                                  fox       quick     over
Slop 1:                                 fox|quick           over                                       
Slop 2:                   quick         fox                 over
Slop 3:    quick                        fox                 over
```

total steps 3

**Query 2:**

```
            Pos 1         Pos 2         Pos 3     Pos 4   Pos 5   Pos 6  Pos 7   Pos 8
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Doc:        quick         brown         fox       jumps    over    the   lazy    dog
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Query:                    over          fox       quick
Slop 1:                   over          fox|quick            
Slop 2:                   quick|over    fox           
Slop 3:     quick         over          fox       
Slop 4:     quick                       over|fox      
Slop 5:     quick                       fox       over
Slop 6:     quick                       fox               over
```

Total steps 6

Comment: Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

So, I reproduced the issue, with the mapping you provided and was able to troubleshoot the issue, with the help of [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) and [this](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-use-slop-with-phrase-search-in-elasticsearch-6) article on slop in match_phrase queries.

So your second query gives result when minimum `slop of 6` is given as shown in my search result.

### Search query

```
{
 "query": {
   "match_phrase": {
     "title": {
       "query": "over fox quick", "slop": 6 --> note 6
     }
   }
 } 
}
```

Similarly, you need to give a `minimum slop of 3` to bring the search result from your first query.

**Basically slop value means, allowable deviation of the configurable term.**

Example:- your doc contains `Quick Brown fox jumps over the lazy dog`.

```
Quick
Brown
fox
jumps
over
the
lazy 
dog
```

**And if you are searching for `fox quick over` as a phrase, they all need to come together**, for that you need to rearrange the tokens mentioned above.

**Minimum replacement required is 3 as shown following:**

`fox` and `over` no need to change anything, as they are already in order and `quick` needs to make 3 replacement, in order to come to its correct position.

Using the same method you can figure out why six slop is required in your second query to work.

Comment: Thanks for answering :)