# Search string keyword by elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, search, optimization

I have an issue to implement elasticsearch with the query "**energy saving tv**".
I have 3 objects with "title" field:

T1: Phone with LG application is an **energy saving tv**

T2: That **tv** made by **energy saving** LG applications

T3: Phone with LG application ensures optimal **energy saving**

Then I used "**match**" and "**AND**" operator for query "energy saving tv":

```
GET my_index/_search
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "title": {
                "query": "energy saving tv",
                "operator": "and"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

- Score T1: 5.0
- Score T2: 5.37

So T2's score is higher than T1's score, but I wanna title that has form "energy*saving*tv" (in the order of words in the keyword) will have a score higher. Pls help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Match phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) to match a phrase comprised of several words.

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "title": "energy saving tv"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that this will only match T1 since the exact order is preserved.

If you also want to include other results with a more mixed up or spread apart word order you can add the `slop` parameter.

This will also match T2, but with a lower score:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "title": {
        "query": "energy saving tv",
        "slop": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `slop` basically defines the upper limit to how often you can move a query term to the right or left in order to match the document. It defaults to `0`.

E.g. going from the query `"energy saving tv"` to the document `"energy tv saving"` would require a `slop` of `2`, since `tv` moves one term to the left and `saving` moves one term to the right.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60914779) for a great visual explanation.